# Android: onPreDrawListener didn't removed in custom view inside RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have RecyclerView with custom views. Inside custom view I create an ImageView and add it. Also I adding onPreDrawListener for created ImageView and removed it as soon as onPreDraw callback invoked. But I discovered that at each call of onBindViewHolder will increase calls of onPreDraw callback.
Here is my code example:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

private static final String TAG = CustomView.class.getName();
private static final String VIEW_TAG = "VIEW_TAG";

private ImageView imageView;

private static int counter = 0;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    imageView = new AppCompatImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setTag(VIEW_TAG);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary)));
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    View view = findViewWithTag(VIEW_TAG);
    if (view != null) {
        removeView(view);
    }
    addView(imageView, layoutParams);

    counter++;
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            counter--;

            Log.e(TAG, "Counter: " + counter);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}

private static class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout__item_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

By clicking on item in adapter in logs I see that value of counter variable is decreasing. Instead of have zero value as I expecting. Do anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that this is a [bug in Android SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37068521).